# How to stop update loop with davMail Outlook calendar in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, office365, calendar, caldav

I have installed davMail on my linux machine to act as a conduit/host for my Outlook/Office365 calendar. I am using Thunderbird to view it. The problem is that if I look at the calendar or have a reminder set, about once per second, the whole calendar refreshes (all meetings disappear and reappear, and the reminder window takes focus).
Clearly this is an impossible situation. What is causing the update loop and how do I prevent it?

davMail:

```
Exchange Protocol: O365Maual
OWA or EWS (Exchange) URL: http://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx (greyed out)
Local POP port: 1110
Local IMAP port: 1143
Local SMTP port: 1025
Caldav HTTP port: 1080
Local LDAP port: 1389
Trash keep delay (POP): 30
Sent keep delay (POP): 0
Calendar past events (Caldav): 60
IDLE folder monitor delay: <empty>
```

**Edit:**
As per [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/davmail/discussion/644057/thread/7eb9565d8a/) post, the issue appears to be with calendar events with no end time.

Answer (score 0):

We have Exchange On Premises (not Exchange Online) and use davmail for calendar access via caldav.

Since Thunderbird 91 we noticed, that the calendar flickers, when a meeting response exists in ones inbox. Workaround: Delete meeting responses as soon as possible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).